# Random Boolean Value

Tags: c++, random, ctime

I'm trying to generate a random int that is either 0 or 1 in C++. Right now, I receive a 0 every time I run this code, and I'm not sure why. What's the problem here?

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

srand(time(0));
int randomval = rand() % 2;
cout << randomval << endl;
```

Comment: How many times have you run it?

Comment: Try putting the last two lines in a loop and printing multiple values.

Comment: It reminds me of a tossing a coin iPhone app.

Comment: This testcase is not even valid; you have no function block. So you're running some other program. How are we to analyse it if we can't even see it?

Answer (score 218, accepted):

It is called bad luck. Try it again.

Comment: I ran it 100 times in a for loop multiple times. Hopefully you're right.

Comment: Did you call `srand()` on each iteration? Then it should've kept the same number till the next second.

Comment: @RichByden, how many times do you think `time()` is going to change within that loop?

Comment: You're right, I'm really not sure what I was thinking with this one.

Comment: And by the way, I was sranding with each loop iteration.

Comment: This post is too funny...LOL but if someone posts an answer like this today in SO, he will get tons of downvotes...anyway +1..LOL xD

Comment: @devaldcool, not sure what has happened, but today this answer got 14 upvotes and one downvote.

Comment: @Michael I found the screenshot of this answer in a popular Facebook page.. No wonder why you got so many upvotes yesterday

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I also saw the screenshot on the Facebook page of CodeChef... then I dug this answer up by googling and shared it too :)

Comment: @0605002, I see. This is fame ;-)

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I searched on google and found your post. It seems that you have gained 24 upvotes (including mine) since the fb post. BTW you can check you question on [CodeChef's facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/CodeChef/photos/a.10150302285647799.346300.53227312798/10152672968202799/?type=1&theater)

Comment: @InderKumarRathore, thanks, 193 shares, OMG :) BTW, it's not my question, it's my answer ;-)

Comment: Maybe it is quantum entanglement ! Or lacking of seeds.

Comment: @NunoAniceto, I'd say excess of seeds in this case.

Answer (score 28):

I know this is an older question but I believe this answers the question properly.

Don't re-seed the the generator every time you run that code.

By seeding it to the same value every time, you're just gonna get the same "random" number. Remember this is a Pseudo-Random number generator, so based on the seed value, a "random" number will be generated. So if you seed it with the same number every time you're just gonna get the same number every time.

The solution is to call srand(time(NULL)) only once in your program execution. Then, each call to rand() will give you a different number every time.

Answer (score 4):

On theory, there's 50% chance you get `0`, and 50 - `1`. You may want to try with different modulo - for example 100, to check if this works. And I'm sure it does.

You have just ran this code a few times, not enough.

Other idea to test it:

```
srand(time(0));
for( int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i )
{
    assert( 0 == ( rand() % 2 ) );
}
```

Comment: -1: Do _not_ `srand` in a loop! Do it at the start of your program and never again.

Comment: @UncleBens - because the @OP didn't believe, that `rand` returns (pseudo) random value?

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add that when you use `srand(time(0));` the "random number" will always be the same in the same second. When I tried to run your program 10000 times and group it by uniq I saw that the number would not change within a second.

```
for i in `seq 1 10000`; do ./a.out; done | uniq -c
    693 0
   3415 1
    675 0
    673 1
    665 0
    674 1
    668 0
    711 1
    694 0
    673 1
    459 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
bool random() {
    if (rand() % 2 == 0)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Comment: Why are you testing and then returning what you have tested. Remember, if your if only has `return true` and your else only has `return false`, it is always better to just return what you are testing. i.e. `return rand() % 2 == 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Call `srand(time(NULL));` just once.

Then use a loop like this, you will always get a 0 or 1 this way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

srand(time(NULL));

for (i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    printf("%d\n",rand() % 2);
    i++;
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Maybe add an explanation of what `srand` needs to be called.

Answer (score 0):

Although your code suggests that you want to receive them equally likely, you didn't state that, and perhaps you have simply thought that it was impossible to do otherwise. If you want a different distribution, and you are willing to rewrite your code (and make it C++11 compliant), you can do the following:

```
    const double chance = 0.3; // this is the chance of getting true, between 0 and 1;
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 mt(rd());
    std::bernoulli_distribution dist(chance);
    bool result = dist(mt);
```

If you will need to do that in a loop, only repeat the last statement `dist(mt)`, keep all the generated objects as they are without recreating them.

Answer (score -2):

You are not checking against anything. Use:

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

srand(time(0));
int randomval = rand() % 2 == 0;
cout << randomval << endl;
```